# Using Aspose.Slides For Python With MacOS

Tags: python, aspose, aspose-slides

I'm utilising aspose.slides for Python successfully on Windows, recently they've added MacOS support. When I try to run ANY aspose.slides script on MacOS I get an error that it can't find libpython dylib in /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib

Simple example

```
import aspose.slides as slides

# Instantiate a Presentation object that represents a presentation file
with slides.Presentation() as presentation:
    slide = presentation.slides[0]
    slide.shapes.add_auto_shape(slides.ShapeType.LINE, 50, 150, 300, 0)
    presentation.save("NewPresentation_out.pptx", slides.export.SaveFormat.PPTX)
```

I've added a symbolic link from /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib directory to the libpython file but now I get the error “zsh segmentation fault”

I've googled and tried so many things but always the same result. Can anyone shed any light on where I maybe going wrong please?

Comment: Hey Luke, any update on this? Having the same segmentation fault on my end too.

Comment: @A.Debugne Unfortunately not. I have left it for now and got done what I can with python-pptx

Comment: OK, thanks for the reply. This seems to be an open issue with Aspose.Slides on MacOS: https://forum.aspose.com/t/does-aspose-slides-for-python-via-net-work-on-macos/250037/24.